# samba4 provision error

Tags: samba

after instlling samba4 with the last message to be successful, i've tried to provision but got the following errors:

```
ldb: module schema_load intialization failed: no such object
ldb: module rootdse intitialization failed: no such object
ldb: module samba_dsdb initilization failed: no such object
ldb: unable to load modules for /usr/local/samba/private/sam.ldb/ null smbd-connect failed
ufs.connect failed
Error class samba provision provisionerrror
provision failed your file system or build does not support posix
ACLs, which s3fs reqiores - try mounting file system acl.

file /usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-package/samba/netcmd/domain.py
line 427
in run
```

I've tried the provision many times.
is there any way to fix this samba4 installation?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the samba-dsdb-modules package, which contains the LDb modules that  are mentioned in the error message.

Run:

```
apt-get install samba-dsdb-modules
```